# iOS - Clickable invisible segment control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there any way to make a segment control invisible while still being clickable? I've tried playing with the alpha settings but can't go below .02 and have it still be clickable. This seems the most convenient solution to my problem but if its imposible i can figure something else out.

Comment: Controls with alpha less then 0.02 (or something like that) do not get touch events so your solution will now work as easy as you want. May be tell us what your actual problem is and we'll get better solution for it?

Comment: Why do you want an invisible UISegmentControl? Are you displaying images behind it that you want to show through? If so, you can change segment images and the tintColor property to get a similar effect with much less hassle.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is I have a grid of dots(the buttons) and when I tap a pair of dots a line is drawn between them. So I need a way to capture touch events occurring in the general area of each dot and a way to tell which dot is being touched so I can draw the line in the proper area. The lines are why I wanted transparent buttons, because by my understanding of how views are layered if I drew the lines on top they would interfere with the touch events on the lower layer of buttons. A segment control just seemed like the easiest way I knew of setting up the sort of grid I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting its background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Doesn't work because the background color of a segment view is not the images of the actual segments.

Comment: I suggest you then use a UIButton with a background color set to clearColor. This will provide you with an "invisible" tapping area.

Comment: I'll see how that works... kinda wanted to avoid making 100 individual buttons :P

Comment: Thanks, please mark my response as the answer by clicking the tick next to it. This will also encourage others to answer your future questions.